# Regex - excluding words but with wildcards

Tags: python, regex

May not be possible with one expression but here goes.

```
txt = 'check from HERE and i need RED but not BLUE'
```

For the above text I need an expression that will match if 'RED' appears **anywhere** after 'HERE' but 'BLUE' does not appear **anywhere** after HERE.

Comment: Look at negative lookaheads: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @user3080953, i found what I need. Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: @TokyoD Please post the answer there for others in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity:

## Without regular expressions

```
txt = 'check from HERE and i need RED but not BLUE'
after_here = txt.split('HERE', 1)[1]
result = red in after_here and blue not in after_here
```

## Regular expression

```
^.*HERE(?!.*BLUE.*).*RED.*$
#   ^ look after 'HERE'
#           ^ negative lookahead in everything that comes after HEAD for BLUE
#                     ^ look for RED in everything that comes after HEAD

// see https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround2.html
```

Comment: For your first option, what if there are multiple `HERE`?  You should only split once using `txt.split('HERE', 1)`.